# Scaling limit of transport equation with double-well potential

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, hyperbolic-pde

Let us consider the transport PDE
$$
u^\epsilon_t + u^\epsilon_x= -\frac{1}{\epsilon} W'(u^\epsilon)
$$
where $W$ is a double-well potential -- for example, $W(x)=\frac{1}{4}(x^2-1)^2$ so that the PDE reads
$$
u^\epsilon_t + u^\epsilon_x= \frac{1}{\epsilon} u^\epsilon\big(1-(u^\epsilon)^2\big).
$$

Does the limit of $u^\epsilon$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ exists? Can it be characterized?